# How can I delete all the comments in my code?

Tags: c#, comments

I'm new to C#, and want to develope a program with which I could delete the comments after `//` in my code. Is there any simple code recommended for this purpose?

Comment: Why would you want to delete all the comments??

Comment: What about comments enclosed in /* and */ You want them gone too?

Comment: I guess one way would just be to compile it.  The resulting output will have no comments.

Comment: might make an interesting parsing exercise, or as part of an obfuscator?

Comment: @commenters: Come on, If you want to practice File I/O source code is an easily available source. Let's assume it's not for a serious tool.

Comment: You do know that compiling removes all the comments, right? This is *not* an optimization technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point, this seems like a bad idea. Comments are useful.

Taking it as an exercise,

#### Edit: This is a simple solution that will fail on all the case @Bubbafat mentions (and propbably some more). It would still work OK on most source files.

1. read the text one line at a time.
2. find the *last* occurrence of `//`, if any using `String.LastIndexOf()`
3. remove the text after (including) the '//' when found
4. write the line to the output

   - ad 1: You can open an TextReader using `System.IO.File.OpenText()`, or `File.ReadLines()` if you can use Fx4
   - Also open an output file using `System.IO.File.WriteText()`
   - ad 3: `int pos = line.LastIndexOf("//"); if (pos >= 0) { line = line.Substring(0, pos); }`

Comment: @Henk Holterman what is the command to remove the text in c#? sorry for the newbie question?

Comment: Assuming that `//` is not within literal text.

Comment: @Matthew: right, a program along these lines would _not_ work on itself. I'm not going to fix that.

Comment: lol... what you don't want to put hours into writing a state machine parser to answer a question :o)

Comment: @Matthew: It would be fun if someone came up with a (monster) RegEx to do this right.

Comment: @Henk i doub't it can be done with a RegEx, C# isn't a regular language

Answer (score 4):

It has been suggested that you just search for "//" and trim.

Because you have limited yourself to single-line commands this seems like a relatively simple exercise however it has some tricky cases you need to be thinking about if you intend for the output of the program to be a valid C# application with identical behavior to the input program.

Here are some examples where just searching for "//" and trimming won't work.

**Comment in Literal:**

```
string foo = "this is // not a comment";
```

**Comment in Comment**

```
/* you should not trim // this one */
```

**Comment in Comment Part Deux**

```
// This is a comment // so don't just remove this!
```

**Multi-line Comment Adjacency**

```
/* you should not *//* trim this these */
```

There are certainly other edge cases but these are some low-hanging fruit to think about.

Comment: +1.  Right on.  Don't forget about multiline verbatim string literals, such as `string foo = @"... (line break) ... // something (line break) ... ";` [Since I can't put actual line breaks in a comment, imagine they're there.]  That means that, to be fully correct, you can't go line-by-line.  You must implement a parser.